# At least 4 Spades among 5 Cards

Tags: combinatorics

I have seen other similar questions and I know that the answer is
$$
\binom{13}{4}\binom{39}{1} + \binom{13}{5}
$$
But my question why is the following wrong:
$$
\binom{13}{4}\binom{48}{1}
$$
Reasoning: Choose $4$ spades out of $13$, and $1$ card from remaining $48$

Comment: I think it would help if you try to explain how you got to that answer. And your thinking behind it

Comment: Made edits for this

Comment: The second is wrong because you are over counting. Suppose the first term includes A,2,3,4 of spades and the second term, Q of spades. You would count as separate another distribution of Q,2,3,4, in the first term and ace in the second term once more. There could be an unknown number of such overcounts.

Comment: To try to 'guess' what is wrong, you should compute both formulas : 715*39+1287=29172 for the correct formula, and 715*48=34320 for your formula. 34320 is greater than 29172, so you over-count some cases. And, if we look further, we can see that the difference 34320-29172, it is $4*\binom{13}{5}$

Comment: @trueblueanil: Please don't answer in comments. If the question is worth answering, write an answer. Not only is it more likely for comments to be deleted, an answer can be accepted, telling people that there is a good response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Short answer to your specific query  from comments*

The second is wrong because you are over counting. Suppose the first term includes A,2,3,4 of spades and the second term, Q of spades. You would count as separate another distribution of Q,2,3,4, in the first term and ace in the second term once more

*Further elaboration*

In problems like this of the "at least" type, you need to divide the population into two disjoint parts, say, "specified" and "others". Here "specified" are "spades" and "others" are "non-spades", and in general, summation is needed. If we wanted to find the number of ways to get at least $7$ spades in $9$ cards, say, the answer would be

$\binom{13}7\binom{39}2 + \binom{13}8\binom{39}1 +\binom{13}9\binom{39}0$

We can avoid summation only if at least $1$ spade in $9$ is asked for, where we can use the complement, viz.

{All possible hands of $9$} - {Hands of $9$ with no spades}